# C# Datetime conversion with the same operation of javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, datetime, utc, toisostring

Good morning,
I have this string format `"1444050466000"` and if I use javascript I can convert it in a value type date.

Example:

```
var b = "1444050466000";
var isoDate = new Date(b).toISOString('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z');
```

result: 2015-10-05T13:07:46.000Z

My question is, there is a way to do the same conversion in C#?

Comment: Welcome on SO! Please format your code samples properly when writing questions. It will help others to understand your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a base `DateTime` representing a Unix Timestamp (1.1.1970 UTC) and add the milliseconds: `new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc).AddMilliseconds(1444050466000)`